# How to get the result stored in the counter from a Hama BSPJob?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bsp, hama

Similar to Hadoop Mapreduce, Hama also has Counters as explained in this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hama/BSPModel#Counters).

In hadoop mapreduce, retrieving the value of a Counter is as simple as follows using the [getCounters()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#getCounters%28%29) function:

```
long value = job.getCounters().findCounter(SomeEnumClass.PROPERTY).getValue();
```

However, in hama's [BSPJob](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hama/hama-core/0.5.0/org/apache/hama/bsp/BSPJob.java) class, it does not have such a `getCounters()` function.

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getCounters()
location: class org.apache.hama.bsp.BSPJob
      long value = bsp.getCounters().findCounter(
                         ^
1 error
```

So my question is: After a hama BSPJob has finished, how can I retrieve the value from a Counter?

Thank you,

Comment: Frankly I think you will need to add a feature request (issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAMA).

Comment: @Thomas OMG ... I know you're an expert on Hama, and if you don't think there is a way .. then that means there might not be such a way .. :(.  So is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't have the latest release on disk, but it looks like we simply forgot to add this. So I guess you will need to parse it from the log output. But please double check with the dev team.

Comment: Originally I tried something like `bsp.getJobClient().getJob().getStatus().getCounter().findCounter()`, but it turns out that `getJobClient()` is package-private ....

Comment: You can add a proxy in the hama package in your project and access it from there. Although that is not very convenient.

Comment: In that case I will think about submit a solution to hama (in case I do it right) :p